# declaring global variable which gives seg fault in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have some code in assembly in which I try to declare a global variable with AT&T syntax in x86-64, and I cannot figure out why it seg faults:

```
    .section .note.GNU-stack,""
    .global randint
    .global fill_array
    .global dot
    .global dot_struct
    .text

.data
    seed: .quad 0

randint:
    # mov seed into rax
    lea seed(%rip), %rdi
    mov (%rdi), %rax
    ret

fill_array:
    ret

dot:
    ret

dot_struct:
    ret
```

Comment: How do you assemble and link your program?  Please make sure your [mcve] is actually reproducable.

Comment: Function code belongs in `.text`